# Calculate average of every 5 samples with rrdtool or other languages

Tags: bash, perl, rrdtool

I want to make an average of 5 samples and calculate a single value:

Current output - I put resolution of 5 minutes but receive 5 samples:

```
$ rrdtool fetch file.rrd  AVERAGE -r 300 --start 1200000000 --end 1200000300
1200000000: 1.3938888889e+00
1200000060: 4.9572222222e+00
1200000120: 7.1675000000e+00
1200000180: 1.0982500000e+01
1200000240: 7.6136111111e+00
1200000300: 7.2169444444e+00
```

Desired result:

```
$ rrdtool fetch file.rrd  AVERAGE -r 300 --start 1200000000 --end 1200000300
1200000000: 1.3938888889e+00
1200000300: x.xxxxxxxxxxe+00 - average
```

I want calculate it with rrdtool or other language like perl, bash, etc...

Comment: post a small amount of the source data

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` command only retrieves data from the raw RRA; if you do not have an RRA of the requested granularity, then the nearest available will be used, but no additional calculations will be performed.

Add a new RRA to your RRD file when you create your RRD file, with a 1cdp==5pdp rule. EG

```
    rrdtool create file.rrd -s 60 
        DS:ds0:GAUGE:120:0:100 
        RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:400 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:5:400
```

This example sets 400 rows; you may wish to use more.

When you have a 5pdp RRA, then you can use `rrdtool fetch -r 300`, otherwise if you only have a 1pdp RRA, you can only use a resolution of 60 (one step).

You may also like to take a look at `rrdtool xport` which (in the same way as `rrdtool graph`) allows you to define output calculated values which can be summaries.

```
   rrdtool xport  --step 300 --start 1200000000 --end 1200000300
        --maxrows 400
        DEF:value=file.rrd:ds0:AVERAGE
        XPORT:value
```

This assumes your DS to be names `ds0` of course, and is not as efficient as doing a `fetch` when you already have the required RRA.